# How to add column in text file in c

Tags: c, text, fseek

I have a text file that has 3 columns - [[Image of input txt file]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lh0lx.png)

I want to add new column. like this - [[Image of output txt file]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yxef8.png) (new column is average of 2nd and 3rd column)

I have done this by reprinting the whole line -

```
for (i=0; i<180; i++)
{
    fscanf(input, "%i %f %f", &std_id[i], &cg_1[i], &cg_2[i]);

    cg_avg[i] = (cg_1[i] + cg_2[i]) / 2;
    printf("%i\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\n", std_id[i], cg_1[i], cg_2[i], cg_avg[i]);
}

fclose(input);

FILE *output = fopen("ME_L1_T2.txt", "w");
for(i = 0; i<180; i++)
{
    fprintf(input, "%i\t\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\n", std_id[i], cg_1[i], cg_2[i], cg_avg[i]);
}

fclose(output);
```

**But, now, I have to do it by fseek() function. I have no idea that how I can add a column by fseek() function. Help me about that.**
Thank you...

Comment: I would say you simply can't do this with `fseek`.

Comment: One way I can think about doing this is to read the entire file into a buffer, then use a regex to skip past the first and second "columns" ideally it would just need to jump past some text and a \t , then insert your text, repeat for the next line.

Comment: But, really, you can't (or you don't want to) "insert text".  You simply can't insert text into a file, at least in C's file model; you have no choice but to rewrite the file.  And if you have one in-memory buffer containing an entire file, then while it's theoretically possible to insert text into it, it's inevitably going to involve lots of unnecessarily inefficient copying of characters to the right, to make room for insertion.